# I really need some help with a plant identification

Tags: botany, species-identification

I am trying to identify this flower. It was spotted in an Australian Botanic Gardens. I have been advised that the plant was approx 1.8m high and the flowers approx 2cm wide. Any help greatly appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That's an Apocynaceae, from the species [*Strophanthus speciosus*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strophanthus_speciosus). Its common name here in Australia is corkscrew flower or poison rope.

It's not native to Australia, though: it's native to Africa.

You can easily identify it by the flower:

[image]

<sup>Flowers of *Strophanthus speciosus* in the Royal Botanic Gardens Victoria, Melbourne ([source of the image](http://melbournedaily.blogspot.com.au/2015/02/melbourne-street-trees-102-corkscrew.html))</sup>

Comment: I would just like to send my sincere thanks for your help Gerardo. I appreciate it very much.

Comment: Ann, please consider accepting Gerardo's answer as correct if you think the case is settled.

Comment: @Sudachi Thanks for the comment, but this is OP's first question. According to my experience at StackOverflow, OP is probably not going to see this comment anyway... most of 1-question wonders never come back or simply open a new account when they want to make another question.

Comment: Yes, I see it quite often. Wish sometimes these could be voted on to close them. It was nice of her to thank you so I thought she might be able log back in and accept the answer. I'll keep my fingers crossed.

Comment: Yes, indeed. But that's the policy of **all** SE sites, we cannot force OP to do anything: accept an answer, upvote, downvote, whatever. I'm used to it: in my last ten answers I have more than 140 upvotes, but no one was accepted.

Comment: My sincere apologies If I have failed to do what was expected. I really am so sorry! This is indeed my first time here, I logged in from facebook but I shall be starting an account here if that is OK. I do not know how much I can give to the community but I shall do whatever I can. Sudachi, could you please advise me on how to 'accept' Gerardo's answer? I would be most grateful.

Comment: It is fine, I can see now what I should have clicked on. I am truly sorry Gerardo for that! I was incredibly grateful for you identifying that plant for me. I do floral photography and sometimes plants are wrongly identified or not named at all. It can get quite frustrating at times. I owned a plant nursery for many years so have a fair knowledge of local plants but some I still struggle with sadly!

Comment: No worries @AnnElliott, that's not a big deal! Next time you need help regarding identification just add the tag `species-identification` to your question, people here like those challenges, they are like little puzzles.